# C : How to link all o file into one file

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile

I try to integrate a C library into my project. The custom makefile of this project try to compile all source files, each file into one object file (`*.o`).

I need to link all of those `*.o` files into one file, for example `so` file, for easily to use it. Do I need this ? And if yes, how can I link all of `*.o` files into one library file. Which lines I will add to Makefile ?

(Notes that, this C library include many sub-directory, and a big makefile will go into all sub directories, and use Makefile in each directory to run it)

Thanks :)

Comment: [example](https://github.com/mrbald/cxxblocks/blob/master/build/plugins/cpp_targets.mk), search for "linking shared library" text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this is best [document](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html).

Lets see i have 2 .o files. ctest1.o ctest2.o
so i will make static library as follows way.

```
ar -cvq libctest.a ctest1.o ctest2.o
```

For dynamic .so file

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c *.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libctest.so.1 -o libctest.so.1.0   *.o
mv libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib
ln -sf /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libctest.so.1
ln -sf /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libctest.so
```

This creates the library libctest.so.1.0 and symbolic links to it.